# How to index attribute values not associated to a product in Algolia with Magento?

Tags: magento, search, algolia

im currently using Algolia with my Magento shop. Is it possible to index attribute values which are not associated to a product.

ie. I have an attribute called Brand with over 1000 values. But only 50 of them are associated with atleast one product. 
I would like to index all 1000 brand values in Algolia, so that i can use them in different request.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way is to write a small script to and index them yourself on an other index.  You can have a look at how additional attributes index are getting their values => https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/code/Helper/Entity/Additionalsectionshelper.php

Comment: okay, yes that has worked. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to write a small script to and index them yourself on an other index. You can have a look at how additional attributes index are getting their values => https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/code/Helper/Entity/Additionalsectionshelper.php